# Variation on rod cutting (size of rods can change)

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

[This is an assignment, please don't give me the full code.] 
I need to write a function that receives two lists, one with the stock of rods (their sizes vary), and one with the order and returns either "False, []" (if it's not possible to answer order) or "True, how_to" where how_to is a list in which each item is the index of the rod used to supply for the corresponding item in order.

E.g.:

```
stock = [100, 150]
order = [30, 60, 90, 60]
how_to = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Any solution that works is accepted ([0,0,1,1], [0,1,1,0], [1,1,0,1] etc). The function has to be recursive.

```
how_to = []
def process(stock, order):

    stock_size = 0  
    order_size = 0

    for i in order:
        order_size += i
    for i in stock:
        stock_size += i

    if order_size > stock_size:
        return False, []

    elif len(order) == 0:
        return True, how_to

    else:

        for i in range(len(stock)):
            if len(stock) > 0:
                if stock[i] >= order[0]:
                    stock[i] -= order[0]
                    how_to.append(i)
                    del order[0]
                    process(stock, order)
            else:
                return True, how_to
        return False, []
```

This far this is what I wrote. However, it only works if items in how_to are increasing (i.e., if the solution uses the stock in the order in appears). Cases like process([60,70,50], [45,5,25,30,55]) don't work. I need help fixing it.

I know that my solution isn't dynamic but it's what I could come up with.

There are some requirements:
(1) I can't sort the lists.
(2) I can't add another argument to the function.

Comment: This code is not recursive. It'd need to be a function `feasible(stock, order, how_to)` which calls itself, each time unpeeling one element from the list `order`.

Comment: @smci how_to is a global variable, so it does the same thing as feasible(stock, order, how_to) would do, i guess. it's recursive since it has a base case (order is empty), it calls itself and every time it gets closer to the base case (by deleting one element of order after checking it), isn't it?

Comment: in a recursive approach, there are no 'global variables'. Your recursive function would simply propagate `how_to` back up as its result. In fact, you don't need to return a tuple `True, how_to` since we can infer it was feasible from the fact that `how_to` was non-empty. I'll sketch this out in an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "crescent"?  Increasing?  You can't guarantee that there will be a non-decreasing solution.  For instance, ([10, 20], [20, 10]) has only one solution: [1, 0], in which **how_to** is decreasing.

Comment: If you mean that one of the other arguments must be non-decreasing, then simply note the original order, sort the list, call your function, and then apply the inverse transformation on the solution.

Comment: @Prune sorry, edited the question for further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's collapse the head of your routine for easier reading.  The **sum** method sums the elements of a list.  Thus, everything before your **elif** collapses to:

```
if sum(order) > sum(stock):
   return False, []
```

Next, fix the logic of your **for** loop control.  One important concept in programming is that you should *not* change **for**-loop parameters once you enter the loop.  In this case, altering **stock** from within the loop is a bad idea.  Instead, when you recur, pass in altered copies of the arguments, such as

```
reduce = stock[:]   # copy stock
reduce[i] -= order[0]
process(reduce, order.pop(0))
```

Now, you have a flaw in the recursion logic: you never use the return result.  Instead of making **how_to** a global variable, you should make it local, keep any solution you find, and pass back the result, adding the present cut.

The idea is more like this:

```
for each rod in stock:
    if I can cut the first rod of the order from this,
        simulate making the cut
        update the stock
        recur on the remainder of the order
        if that recursion works,
            append the simulated cut to this solution,
            return success
# If I get here, I didn't find any solution
return failure
```

By the way, note that having an empty solution list is *equivalent* to failure.  I don't see why the assignment has you also return True or False.

---

Added hint for the local variable:

Since you need only the one solution, **how_to** is only a temporary convenience, and wouldn't exist at all if this didn't require the leading Boolean.  The solution should exist *only* in the return value.

```
if len(order) == 0:
    return True, []

...
    found, how_to = process(reduce, order[1:])
    if found:
        how_to.append(i)
    return found, how_to
```

There it is: if you found a solution for N-1 rods, then simply append the cut you made in this iteration, and pass the N-rod solution up the line.

Comment: thanks! i didn't use sum() because we need to write everything manually, from sort() to sum() etc. 
your answer was very helpful, but i still haven't figured out how to make **how_to** a local variable: if i write it inside _process_ it's restarted every time i call it again (for recursion) and i lose my results. if i could pass it as an argument i'd know how to do it, but since i can't...